# Large difference in the time it takes to compute the transpose of a matrix

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning

This is a simplified version of the program I'm working on. I'm working with some large vectors that I have to transpose at the end in order to get the result I'm looking for. I have two versions of the program, both giving the same result, but one taking way longer than the other:

```
n = 200.; 
m = 300000;
p = Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}], m];

(* First program *)

AbsoluteTiming[Q = Reap[Do[Sow[( {p, p}*{i/50, i^2/100}), 1];
  Sow[( {p, p}*{i/50, i^2/100}) // Transpose, 2];, {i, n}]][[2]];]
AbsoluteTiming[v11 = Q[[1]]; v21 = Q[[2]] // Transpose;]

{1.79722, Null} (* Time it takes to compute the two vectors, Q[[1]] and Q[[2]] *)
{1.02865, Null} (* Mainly time it takes to transpose Q[[2]], as setting v11=Q[[1]] takes about 10^-6 seconds *)

(* Second program *)

v12 = v22 = Table[0, {i, n}];


AbsoluteTiming[Do[v12[[i]] = ({p, p}*{i/50, i^2/100});
v22[[i]] = ({p, p}*{i/50, i^2/100}) // Transpose;, {i, n}]]
AbsoluteTiming[vec1 = v22//Transpose;]

{1.78438, Null} (* Time it takes to compute the two vectors, v12 and v22 *)
{14.5686, Null} (* Time it takes to transpose v22 *)
```

As you can see, the computation time is the same in both programs, but there's a huge difference when transposing the matrix at the end. When m is larger, the second program even crashes due to memory issues when trying to transpose the matrix, while the first one takes only a few seconds. When checking at the end, both vectors are identical:

```
v22 == Q[[2]]
vec1 == v21

True
True
```

How can there be such a huge difference in the time it takes transposing two identical matrices?

Comment: What Mathematica version are you on? I can't reproduce the timing difference you're reporting.

Comment: Better use `n=200; v12 = ConstantArray[0., {n, 2, Np}]; v22 = ConstantArray[0., {n, Np, 2}];`  to initialize your arrays. This will make sure that you the arrays stay packed.

Comment: @Sjoerd Smit I'm using Mathematica 11.3

Comment: Times for MMA12.1 on Windows 10: {1.23631, Null}

{0.758216, Null}

{1.27595, Null}

{0.76083, Null} It seems Wolfram did some work between version 11 and 12.

Comment: These are pretty large arrays and `Transpose` is memory bound. So if you have already quite a lot of other data in RAM, this might force the operating system to swapping. Then timings are pretty unpredictable...

Comment: Btw., I would do it like this: `n = 200;
Np = 300000;
p = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, Np];
v12 = Transpose[{TensorProduct[0.02 Range[1., n], p],TensorProduct[0.01 Range[1., n]^2, p]}];`